# Delete an item from List

Tags: android, list, view, listitem

I'm creating an app that scans bar codes, saves them in a db and manages them through a list.
So, these are classes that interested in my problem

Main

```
@Override
  public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.scanner_menu);

      Button addButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.addMenuButton);
      addButton.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick (View v){
              startActivity(new Intent(CodiceBarreActivity.this, AggiungiCodiceActivity.class));
          }
          });

      Button listButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.ViewlistButton);
      listButton.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick (View v){
              startActivity(new Intent(CodiceBarreActivity.this, ProdottiSelectionActivity.class));
          }
          });

  }   

static final class ProductData {
    long _id;
    String barcode;
    String format;
    String title;
    String price;
}
```

}

helper

```
  private SQLiteDatabase db;

public ProductDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

    sql.append("create table ")
        .append(PRODUCT_TABLE)
        .append("(  ")
        .append("   _id integer primary key,")
        .append("   barcode text,")
        .append("   format text,")
        .append("   title text,")
        .append("   price text")
        .append(")  ");

    db.execSQL(sql.toString());    

    Log.d(TAG, PRODUCT_TABLE + "table created");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + PRODUCT_TABLE);       
      Log.d(TAG, PRODUCT_TABLE + "table dropped");
        onCreate(db);
}
```

db

```
private static final String PRODUCT_TABLE = "products"; 
    private static final BigDecimal ONE_HUNDRED = new BigDecimal("100");
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public CodiciDatabase(Context context) {
        ProductDatabaseHelper helper = new ProductDatabaseHelper(context);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public boolean insert(ProductData product) {
        ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
        vals.put("_id", product._id);
        vals.put("barcode", product.barcode);
        vals.put("format", product.format);
        vals.put("title", product.title);
        vals.put("price", product.price);

        return db.insert(PRODUCT_TABLE, null, vals) != -1;
    }
```

interested class

```
private ProductDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private static final String PRODUCT_TABLE = "products"; 
ProductData product = new ProductData();

@Override
 protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dbHelper = new ProductDatabaseHelper(this);
    }

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + PRODUCT_TABLE, null);

        setListAdapter(new CursorAdapter(this, cursor, true) {
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
            TextView textView = new TextView(ProdottiSelectionActivity.this);
            return textView;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView (View view, Context context, Cursor cursor){

            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            textView.append(cursor.getString(1));
            textView.append("\n");
            textView.append(cursor.getString(2));
            textView.append("\n");
            textView.append(cursor.getString(3));
            textView.append("\n");
            textView.append(cursor.getString(4));
            registerForContextMenu(textView); 
            }

        });
    }

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    dbHelper.close();
    }
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

}
```

}

I need to implement the method onListItemClick so that you delete the selected item.I'm going crazy looking for the right syntax I hope you can help me!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code generation site.

Comment: no but it is a site expert, and I needed that. I will not bother quiet.

Comment: Wall of code == bad. My eyes hurt. Boo hoo.

Comment: if you do not want to be helpful not commented. do more good impression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like you may be getting errors in your "interested class". Your code is a bit confusing in some places, I'm not exactly sure if your using a list view or not. But it would be helpful to use a list view and bind it to a onItemClickListener. You will use `extends ListActivity` in the layout you want to display the items in, make sure to put a listview element in your list view layout. Then to populate your list view, you'll have:

```
        String[] tableColumnNames = new String[] {
                "TABLE COLUMN NAMES SEPARATED BY COMMAS" };
        int[] textViewLabelNames = new int[] { "NAMES OF TEXT VIEW LABELS IN XML ROW LAYOUT" };

        SimpleCursorAdapter stuff = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.your_created_xml_row_layout, cursor, tableColumnNames,
                textViewLabelNames);
        this.setListAdapter(stuff);
```

Then bind your onClickListener:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        //ListView item is clicked
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


    }
    });
```

Referring back to your code:

When `onListItemClick is triggered` you need to delete from the database the row corresponding to the id passed into the onListItemClick method. You then need to update your cursor to reflect the changes on the view by using `cursor.requery()`.

So in order to delete an item from a database with a certain id you can do this:

```
ProductDatabaseHelper helper = new ProductDatabaseHelper(context);
SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
database.delete("TABLE NAME HERE", "NAME OF ID COLUMN HERE" + "=" + id, null);
database.close();
```

You can also view the [SQLiteDatabase Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) for a helpful description of the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work:

```
db.delete("products", "barcode" + "="+ barcodeToDelete, null);
```

replace barcodeToDelte with the value of the barcode that you want to delete from the table. If you won't know the value of the barcode you could delete it based on any of the other fields in your database too by subbing them in for "barcode" in the method above.